# How can I find the currently executing script file and path in python?

Tags: php, python

I am trying to get the file name and directory of the currently executing script and this is the code that works:

```
import inspect, os
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
```

In php this is just `echo dirname(__FILE__)`.  Nice and simple.

There are suggestions that `dirname(__file__)` should work in Python but it returns an empty string when running via the command line.

My question is that why do I have to write all of this code to get the filename:

```
print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
```

and am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__file__` value for the current script is the exact same path you passed to Python; `python yourscript.py` is thus a relative path and doesn't include the directory name. You do need to make it an absolute path, but you do *not* need to use `inspect`:

```
import os.path

print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Demo:

```
$ cat /private/tmp/test.py 
import os.path

print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

$ python /private/tmp/test.py 
/private/tmp
$ cd /private/tmp/
$ python test.py 
/private/tmp
```

In PHP, you have the luxury of the web server executing your files with fully specified absolute paths, so you never saw this 'problem' crop up there.

Comment: `__file__` does not work in the `__main__` module.. if you use the python shell.

Comment: @User: Have you tried it? It works *just fine*. We are not testing against `__name__`, we are using `__file__`, which for the main script is the exact path passed to Python.

Comment: Yes i tried this in a simple script.  Not using the interactive shell.  Simply in main.py.

Comment: @MartyWallace: I never said you were using the interactive shell. My demonstration above is done entirely in Bash. Did you try my version?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is that why do i have to write all of this code to get the filename:
>
> print os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))

Let's take it piece by piece.

First, the `print` is 1 character longer than PHP's `echo`. I doubt you have a problem with that.

Next, you have to use `os.path.dirname` instead of just `dirname` because Python allows code to be organized into modules, and allows you to reference things by qualified name. This is why Python can have functions like `gzip.open` and `io.open` that have the same name. But it doesn't force you to use qualified names if you don't want to; if you'd done, say, `from os.path import dirname` instead of `import os`, you could just use `dirname`.

Next, you need the `abspath` because you may have a relative path. This is actually exactly the same as in PHP. It's just that you're used to running PHP from a web browser setup that always runs your scripts by absolute path. You can do the same in Python if you want.

Finally:

> There are suggestions that `dirname(__file__)` should work in python but it returns an empty string when running via the command line.

Not true.

```
$ cat > test.py
print __file___
$ python test.py
test.py
```

If by "running via the command line" you meant "using the interactive interpreter", of course, there is no `__file__`, because there is no file (except the terminal stdin).

Or, if you're printing the `dirname` of a relative path like `test.py`, of course that's always going to be an empty string, just as it would be in PHP.

Putting it all together:

```
$ cat > test.py
from os.path import dirname
print dirname(__file__)
$ python $(abspath test.py)
/Users/abarnert/src/test
```

Just like PHP.

Comment: I was not using the interactive shell.  I simply have a script main.py

Comment: @MartyWallace: It's very hard to guess what you're doing wrong with minimal information, but my first guess would be exactly what I explained in the very next sentence after the one you replied to: You're running `python main.py`, so `__file__` is the relative path `'main.py'`, so `dirname(__file__)` is `''`. And I'm guessing you didn't bother to look at `__file__`; you just saw that `dirname(__file__)` was empty, and assumed that "`__file__` doesn't work because Python sucks."

Answer (score 0):

In case `__file__` is not set, you can get the directory via

```
import sys, os
script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0] or 'unknown script')
directory = os.path.dirname(script))
```

Comment: That will not give you the absolute path of the file. Just the script name!

Comment: `os.path.abspath()` will use `os.getcwd()` as needed; and `sys.argv[0]` is always set.

Comment: sys.argv[0] is not set in case i use the IDLE without executing a script.

Comment: @User: IDLE is not a normal environment; you are running an interactive interpreter then.

Comment: @User: Well, if you're not executing a script, you don't have a script to get the name of…

Comment: Sure. but when I develop with IDLE and other interpreters that do not set `__file__`, it is annoying if I can not run a module as main and get the path as easy as in your solutions. So just in case.